# Texture Paint bleeding through from back to front

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

When I attempt to texture paint two different areas on the back of the model it bleeds through to the front as seen in the image below. I just need the front to stay black!

Comment: dpes your plane have thickness, and if so, do their faces overlap on the UV map?

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot it appears that your UV map includes overlapping faces. The Texture Paint function is a convenient way of painting onto your mesh and this results in the UV map being used to position the painting into the texture image. If the UV map has faces taking up the same region of the texture image then painting on those faces will result in both faces - since they have been allocated the same part of the image for their texture.

The solution is to re-unwrap your mesh such that each face has its own unique section of the texture image. Try the different Unwrap types. You can also allocate Seams to your edges to give Blender hints as to how to split the UV map when unwrapping.

Comment: I really wanted to research as much as I could before asking such a noob question here. I noticed that the UV map was turning into a complete mess when I would enter texture painting, but being a week or two into using Blender for the first time I guess I don't have the skills to make a correct UV map. Fortunately, I found the kit-ops add-on and because the areas (I was trying to differentiate color in) were all booleans, it worked perfectly. Appreciate the responses and maybe when I get more experienced I will tackle UV mapping :)